# Split method call into multiple lines

Tags: java, coding-style, refactoring

I would like to know which of these options is better in terms of clean (Java) code:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass(
    getParameter1(...), 
    getParameter2(...), 
    getParameter3(...)
);
```

or this one:

```
String param1 = getParameter1(...);
String param2 = getParameter2(...);
String param3 = getParameter3(...);

MyClass myObject = new MyClass(param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: Well if you need the parameters for something else besides creating an instance of `MyClass`, I would say the second option is the best choice. If not the first one is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to use the first one. Cause with the second one you have 3 extra variables that are not used anymore.

Comment: Equally the 2nd one can be easier to debug if you're connecting up a remote socket debugger.

Really a question of personal style more than anything though!

Comment: @Mikey Palfrey you're correct. It's more a personal style thing. That's the reason i gave my own preference as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a duplication of:
[Getter-Setter and private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008180/getter-setter-and-private-variables)

Clean code does tell you to use getters and setters.

To give you the proper answer, you should describe the scenario.